# Updating an iOS app

Tags: ios, updates

I am updating an app in the app store but I am doing a major overhaul to it. I want to work from a new project file and just pull in some of the existing classes I have in the other project.

How do I set up the new project so submission to the app store goes smoothly?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure the bundle ID is the same so that the provisioning profiles still work. That's it.

Comment: I'd suggest try to explain a bit why there're such utter changes in this new version

Comment: Make sure you test both a clean install (like new users of your app would see) and an app update (like existing users of your app would see).

Comment: @BabyPanda - the initial app was more a test for myself on a lot of different things - making SOAP calls, getting something into the app store, etc. I was kind of a newb when I did it. To my surprise it actually turned out to be something that is downloaded quite frequently by people,not Angry Bird levels but 4-5 a day on average.  The UI/UX stunk, I've learned a lot and can streamline a lot of code  and so for me, it's easier to begin with a blank canvas than try to work through my older stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key thing is to make sure the bundle identifier is EXACTLY the same.  Case sensitivity matters here.  As long as the bundle id is the same, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, that's the first thing I made sure of!